# local variable 'sbang' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to return an array that has 1 added to the value represented by the array given the array of any length but I get this error once I execute my code:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sbang' referenced before assignment
```

My code is :

```
def up_array(arr):
    
    for i in arr:
        if i < 0:
            return None
        if i > 9:
            return None
        else:
            sbang = ''.join(map(str, arr))
    a = "0"+str(1+(int(sbang)))
    b = [int(x) for x in str(a)]
    
    if sbang[0] == "0" and len(sbang) > 2:
        return b
    else:
        a = 1+(int(sbang))
    c = [int(x) for x in str(a)]
    return c
```

Any help would highly be appreciated.

I am expecting digits in the array to be added by 1 while saving leading zeros and if there are digits lower than zero and higher than 9 to return None.

What I got was that some of the digits were calculated while for others I got error:

```
local variable 'sbang' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: if `arr` is empty, will the loop execute? If the loop does not execute, is `sbang` being defined? If `sbang` is not defined, does `sbang[0]` has any meaning?

Comment: What is the input that you're using that results in the error, and when exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

In your code if `arr` is empty then the for loop will not be executed and `sbang` will never be initialized. You can fix it by doing:

```py
def up_array(arr):

    for i in arr:
        if i < 0:
            return None
        if i > 9:
            return None
    sbang = "".join(map(str, arr))
    a = "0" + str(1 + (int(sbang)))
    b = [int(x) for x in str(a)]

    if sbang[0] == "0" and len(sbang) > 2:
        return b
    else:
        a = 1 + (int(sbang))
    c = [int(x) for x in str(a)]
    return c
```

Since the initialization of sbang does not depend on the `i` in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The error `local variable 'sbang' referenced before assignment` means to tell you that you're trying to access the `sbang` variable without declaring it. Except, you're declaring the variable on line `sbang = ''.join(map(str, arr))`. So, how could this go wrong?

According to the error, it is possible to reach a line where you access `sbang` (like `if sbang[0] == "0" and len(sbang) > 2:`) without it being declared. So, in which case can the line where you declare `sbang` not be executed?
In the case where `if i > 9:` is always true. So, the next question is. Did you really mean to declare `sbang` at this location? Perhaps you wanted to do it before or after the loop?